# python automation of ArcGIS field calculation

Tags: python, expression

I'm having some issues properly formatting the expression needed to calculate ArcGIS fields using python.

Essentially what I am trying to use is a variable plus a string plus a field.

After trying many different ways, where I'm at now looks like this:

```
abv = "sometext"

expression = "{0}+{1}+!OBJECTID!".format(abv, "-")

arcpy.CalculateField_management(FC, "FIELDNAME", expression)
```

Any thoughts or direction would be awesome.

Comment: You're having some issues?

Comment: would love to know why the down vote and the seemingly sarcastic question/answer.

Comment: I can't see how I could help you without knowing what your issues are.

Comment: Goyo is saying that in order for anyone to help you, you *must* explain what behavior you expect and what different behavior you are actually seeing. "It's not working" is never a sufficient explanation for anyone to actually provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the issue that i was having was that i did not know how to format the expression correctly. so my question was how do i properly format the expression so that it combines a variable plus a string plus a field? however, i have since figured it out:

```
abv = "sometext"  # (this is being pulled from a txt file)

prefix = abv+"-"

expression = "'{0}' + str(!OBJECTID!)".format(prefix)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(FC, "FACILITYID", expression, "PYTHON")
```

This solved the format issue I was having.